# Can I use Visual Studio Express to develop code that will run in MS Windows Server 2003 and MS Access 2003?

Tags: c#

I have a database in MS Access 2003 that is residing in my server running MS Windows Server 2003. I would like to develop C# code to manipulate data in my database. Can I use the free Visual Studio Express to develop the code to run in the previously mentioned environment?

Answer (score 0):

When you download *Visual Studio 2012 Express* it will include very limited functionality.  However, it will accommodate all the *standard* and *basic* Developer goals.  Any functionality that you do not have, can either be added by downloading additional components.  The other option would be to purchase a more advanced version.

By default yes it will work with your environments you asked about.

All the variations can be found [here:](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/compare)

Hopefully that helps.